# how to run a task multiple time on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, pending-transition

I have a task (task #1) to which I give parameters, and it is called by another job.
The calling job call (task #1) 3 times, and I'd like the 3 calls to run simultaneously. Is it because I run the 3 on the same machine that it is not possible?
Else how could I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it. Almost on top of job configuration page is a setting "Execute concurrent builds if necessary". Enable that and you should be ok if you have enough executors available.